# Silverlight Project Advice - Sharing resources between projects in Solution/Projects

Tags: silverlight, xaml

My Visual Studio solution has many projects within it, like a DAL, BLL, UI Forms, etc.  It is getting quite large and now, my Silverlight project that contains all of the UI controls will be splitting up into other more modular projects.  Currently, within my Silverlight project, I have a Resources folder where it has Styles.xaml and other custom dictionaries and an Images folder with images that are used on our UI layer.  I would like to move these Resources (both Dictionaries and Images) into their own project and thus it's own assembly.

My question is, how can I reference these Resources and Images from another project in my Solution?  Any ideas or references will be greatly appreciated.

Currently, I am using stuff like this:

```
<Image Source="../Images/Submit.png" />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use fully qualified assembly references such as below:

> `<Image Source=”/{assemblyName};component/MyImage.jpg”/>`